# trouble getting route to work in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following in my `routes.rb`:

```
resources :resources
match "/resources/:category" => 'resources#index', :as => :resources
```

In my index.html.erb I have the following:L

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <li class="active">
    <%= link_to category.name, resour_path(:category=>category.name.parameterize), :class => "large", remote => true %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

I want to submit to the index action of the `ResourcesController` because I want to show different items on the page as in filter.

The links currently are giving an error as they are calling the show action and not going to the index action.

How can I get them to submit to the index action of the routes controller?

Comment: Please post the error as well as the relevant output of `rake routes`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `match "/resources/:category"` is never reached when going for the route. The path `/resources/some-category` is matched by `resources :resources`, and `some-category` is considered the id for the `show` action.

#### Option 1

Switch the lines so the `match` line is matched first.

```
match "/resources/:category" => 'resources#index', :as => :resources
resources :resources
```

#### Option 2

Turn

```
resources :resources
```

into

```
resources :resources, :except => :show
```

### References

As described in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html:

> Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified, so if you have a resources :photos above a get 'photos/poll' the show action’s route for the resources line will be matched before the get line. To fix this, move the get line above the resources line so that it is matched first.

Comment: I will go with option 1. Thanks